# Swift variable declare with optional(?) or force unwrap(!) different?

Tags: swift

what is different, when we declare new variable post fix with either ? or !

ex:

```
class Car{
   var gear : Int!
   var color : String?
}
```

and I couldn`t find any resource regard of this problem

Comment: Read carefully about [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330). If you already know Optional and Implicitly Unwrapped Optional and still want to ask something, you may need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo?` is an **optional**. `Foo!` is an **implicitly unwrapped optional**.

[This section of the language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID334) explains what implicitly unwrapped optionals are:

> Sometimes it’s clear from a program’s structure that an optional will always have a value, after that value is first set. In these cases, it’s useful to remove the need to check and unwrap the optional’s value every time it’s accessed, because it can be safely assumed to have a value all of the time.

Comment: thanks you for the answer